# serenity - how to use same data in two locations on a single screen

Tags: c#

Suppose added some record in any master screen for one location, and for other location in the same master screen if try to add a record with same code/Description which is already used in the one location then it's not allowed to use same code/Description

Comment: you need to write code to check if the record with the same code/description already existing before adding record. what' the issue you are facing?

Comment: serenity-how-to-use-same-data-in-two-location-on-single-screen